# Add Remove Button on Cloned Field

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

Good day great people, I need help to add Remove button after the cloned happen. The Remove button should remove the cloned field. Any suggestion would be appreciated. Bootply Version - http://www.bootply.com/LiqkgWUFF6

Thanks in advance.

```js
var template = $('#line_1').clone();

$('#cloneButton').click(function () {
    var rowId = $('.row').length + 1;
    var klon = template.clone();          
    klon.attr('id', 'line_' + rowId)
        .insertAfter($('.row').last())
        .find('option')
        .each(function () {
            $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('id').replace(/_(\d*)$/, "_"+rowId));
        })                   
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row" id="line_1">

<div class="form-group col-md-2">
                                <label class="control-label">State</label>
                                        <select class="form-control">
  <option id="Select_1">Select State</option>
  <option id="Selangor_1">Selangor</option>
  <option id="KualaLumpur_1">Kuala Lumpur</option>
  <option id="Malacca_1">Malacca</option>
  <option id="Perak_1">Perak</option>
<option id="Kedah_1">Kedah</option>
</select>
                            </div>
    </div>

<a id="cloneButton" class="btn btn-primary">Add State</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var template = $('#line_1').clone();

$('#cloneButton').click(function () {
    var rowId = $('.row').length + 1;
    var klon = template.clone();   
    console.log(klon)       
    klon.attr('id', 'line_' + rowId)
        .insertAfter($('.row').last())
        .find('option')
        .each(function () {
            $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('id').replace(/_(\d*)$/, "_"+rowId));
        })    

        $("#line_" + rowId).append("<a href='javascript:void(0);' class='remove'>delete</a>")               
});

$(document).on("click", ".remove", function() {
  $(this).closest(".row").remove();
});
```

Comment: Thanks Dhara, really appreciate.

Comment: @Jepf this is the same answer which I posted 5 minutes ahead of this.

Comment: @Dhara Parmar  how it differs from my answer?

Comment: As you can see in your script : After we remove all the selectboxes, Add state is not working at all. you can not add state after deleting all. :)

Comment: yes possible. $("#line_" + rowId).append("<div><a href='javascript:void(0);' class='remove'>delete</a></div>")

Comment: @DharaParmar  What I meant is, how to append the code into existing div, example .form-group div

Answer (score 1):

You can add a remove button on the row div itself and bind the click event using event delegation.

```
var template = $('#line_1').clone();

$('#cloneButton').click(function() {
  var rowId = $('.row').length + 1;
  var klon = template.clone();
  klon.attr('id', 'line_' + rowId)
    .insertAfter($('.row').last())
    .find('option')
    .each(function() {
      $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('id').replace(/_(\d*)$/, "_" + rowId));
    })
});

$(document).on("click", ".remove", function() {
  $(this).closest(".row").remove();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row" id="line_1">
  <div class="form-group col-md-2">
    <label class="control-label">State</label>
    <select class="form-control">
      <option id="Select_1">Select State</option>
      <option id="Selangor_1">Selangor</option>
      <option id="KualaLumpur_1">Kuala Lumpur</option>
      <option id="Malacca_1">Malacca</option>
      <option id="Perak_1">Perak</option>
      <option id="Kedah_1">Kedah</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <input type="button" class="remove" value="remove" />
</div>

<a id="cloneButton" class="btn btn-primary">Add State</a>
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/3447/)

Comment: I see you are using (document).on() function. Delegation is a dangerous thing my friend. This would be a fail attempt if there is anything like `event.stopPropagation()` called in script.

Comment: @FaisalAshfaq can you explain how could it be a dangerous thing? It would be great if you can explain it with a working example. I didn't see a wrapper parent in OP's example, thats why I tried to answer without changing the HTML structure.

Comment: @AnoopJoshi, on load the remove button should not visible. After cloned the remove button should appear.